# <a4j:commandLink> its not calling the action

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, commandlink

i am trying to create a link to the newly created record, and the link i am including inside the success message panel after successful creation of the link, But i am unable to call the action using  tag.

following is my peace of code:

```
<div class="panel-success">
<a4j:outputPanel id="succes_submit">
 <rich:notify stayTime="1000" rendered="#{user.accountsSaved}"
                styleClass="panel-success fsgui-input-panel-success">
<f:facet name="summary">
   <a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" action="#{user.metod}"
         value="#{user.accSeriesInfo.number} :"oncomplete="#{rich:component('details-update')}.show();">                                   

<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{orgseries.accSeriesInfo}" value="#{dataItem}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
<h:outputText value="Record updated successfully "></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
</rich:notify>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</div>
```

instead of **a4j:commandLink** i tried with **h:commandLink** here i am able to call the action but unable to render or perform onComplete operations.

Can any body tell me where is the mistake,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of action attribute try actionListener

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, Still its not working :(

Comment: use a4j:support component in between a4j:commandLink component and try once                                                    <a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" value="#{user.accSeriesInfo.number} :" oncomplete="#{rich:component('details-update')}.show();">
                 <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{user.metod}"></a4j:support>
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{orgseries.accSeriesInfo}" value="#{dataItem}" />
                </a4j:commandLink>

Comment: Did you mention the method in this manner public void metod(ActionEvent event) { //body} after modification of action attribute is changed to actionListener.

Comment: I tried with  actionListener still no progress :( , instead of <a4j:commandLink> i tried with <h:commandLink> here i am able to call the action but unable to render or perform onComplete operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to include the link in rich:notify tag

```
<div class="panel-success" id="success_submit_div">
<a4j:outputPanel id="stru_succes_submit">
 <rich:notify stayTime="1000" rendered="#{emp.saveSuccess}">
<f:facet name="summary">
<h:form>
<a4j:commandLink immediate="true" action="#{emp.getInfo}"  value="# {emp.empId}:"   oncomplete="#{rich:component('edit-Emp-Details')}.show();">
</a4j:commandLink>
<h:outputText value="#{ isEdit ? messages['common.app.save.success'] : messages['employee.create.success']}"></h:outputText>
</h:form>   
</f:facet>
</rich:notify>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</div>
```